# Обтекаемость элементов в сетке при изменении высоты одного из них

Tags: javascript, html, css, scss

Всем привет!
Есть сетка из элементов в несколько столбцов, у каждого элемента есть спойлер с текстом.
Верстка примерно следующая:

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="list__item"></div>
  <div class="list__item"></div>
  <div class="list__item"></div>
  <div class="list__item"></div>
  <div class="list__item"></div>
  <div class="list__item"></div>
</div>
```

То есть только один контейнер, в котором все элементы, внутри больше не может быть никаких дополнительных оберток, то есть нельзя сделать 3 обертки для разделения на 3 столбика.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если раскрыть спойлер, высота элемента с раскрытым спойлером больше, чем у остальных, и он должен сдвинуть элемент, который находится под ним.
Вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас у меня следующий css для формирования сетки, при таком подходе при раскрытом спойлере отодвигается вниз весь нижний ряд, а не элемент под раскрытым элементом:

```
.courses-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.courses-list__item {
  width: calc(33.33333% - 30px);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}
```

Как сделать, что бы при увеличении высоты одного элемента сдвигался только элемент под ним?
По возможности без использования JS

Comment: Очередной вопрос про masonry раскладку

Answer (score 4):

> Верстка примерно следующая

Если примерно, то значит имеется возможность ее немного видоизменить? Если да, то предлагаю следующий вариант (Flex):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: calc(33.33% - 7px);
  margin: 2px;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  margin: 5px 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}


/*спойлер*/
.spoiler {width: 90%; margin: 10px auto; border: 2px solid red;}.spoiler>input+label:after {content: "+"; float: right;}.spoiler>input:checked+label:after {content: "-"; float: right;}.spoiler>input {display: none;}.spoiler>input+label, .spoiler>.spoiler_body {display: block;overflow: hidden;padding: 2px 4px;}.spoiler>input+label+.spoiler_body {height: 0; transition: height 1s;}.spoiler>input:checked+label+.spoiler_body {height: 100px;}.spoiler>.spoiler_body {height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <!-- спойлер-->
    <div class="spoiler"><input type="checkbox" id="spoiler"><label for="spoiler">Спойлер</label><div class="spoiler_body">Текст</div></div>
    <!-- /спойлер-->
  </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

upd. Если верстку не меняем. Простое решение - с `column-count:`, рабочее, правда немного глюканутое, нужно подумать..

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list {
  column-count: 3;
  min-height: 150vh;
}

.list__item {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin: 0 15px 20px 15px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}


/*спойлер*/
.spoiler {width: 90%; margin: 10px auto; border: 2px solid red;}.spoiler>input+label:after {content: "+"; float: right;}.spoiler>input:checked+label:after {content: "-"; float: right;}.spoiler>input {display: none;}.spoiler>input+label, .spoiler>.spoiler_body {display: block;overflow: hidden;padding: 2px 4px;}.spoiler>input+label+.spoiler_body {height: 0; transition: height 1s;}.spoiler>input:checked+label+.spoiler_body {height: 100px;}.spoiler>.spoiler_body {height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list__item"></div>
  <div class="list__item"></div>
  <div class="list__item">
    <!-- спойлер-->
    <div class="spoiler"><input type="checkbox" id="spoiler"><label for="spoiler">Спойлер</label><div class="spoiler_body">Текст</div></div>
    <!-- /спойлер-->
  </div>
  <div class="list__item"></div>
  <div class="list__item"></div>
  <div class="list__item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению так нельзя, как я и написал в вопросе, контейнер с элементами только один, все элементы должны находится рядом. Иначе сложности бы не возникло

Comment: Ответ хорош, но мне кажется это не то, что нужно автору, т.к. в примере (рис 2) показано, что нижний блок не уезжает, а сжимается. А так +.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 нет, он именно уезжает, не сжимается

Comment: @Sevastopol' получается так, под "примерно" я подразумевал разметку внутри элементов и селекторы

Comment: @Arsenij, тогда надо было так и указать в вопросе, а то меня ввели в заблуждение)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 да прошу прощения, действительно так нарисовано, не подумал об этом(

Comment: @Sevastopol' если другого выхода нет, то конечно)

Comment: @Sevastopol', попробую..

Comment: @Sevastopol' эти элементы приходят динамически с сервера, сервер не хочет их делить на дополнительные обертки-колонки и распределять элементы между ними, так как самих элементов может быть абсолютно разное кол-во

Comment: @Sevastopol' я оставил этот вариант на самый крайний случай, не очень хотелось использовать, потому что там есть фильтр, результатом которого являются как раз эти элементы, и тогда придется при каждом запросе вызывать этот js. Но сделаю тогда сам. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой вариант использовать `column`, но при условии, что вам не важно расположение, потому что колонки выстраиваются **сверху-вниз**:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

```css
.list {
  display: block;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.list__item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 4em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list__item .spoiler {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5em;
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.list__item .spoiler::before {
  content: 'show +';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.list__item .spoiler:focus {
  height: 5em;
}

.list__item .spoiler:focus::before {
  content: 'hide -';
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list__item">
    <!-- псевдоспойлер -->
    <div class="spoiler" tabindex="-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="list__item">
    <div class="spoiler" tabindex="-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="list__item">
    <div class="spoiler" tabindex="-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="list__item">
    <div class="spoiler" tabindex="-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="list__item">
    <div class="spoiler" tabindex="-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="list__item">
    <div class="spoiler" tabindex="-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Думаю, что лучше всего использовать для этого Mansory, ибо увы, пока CSS именно так не умеет..

Comment: да, думал об этом тоже, но расположение важно